# Trying to extract nested json data into a vertical list

Tags: python, json, python-requests, pycharm

How can I extract all the tank names from this url
(https://api.wotblitz.com/wotb/encyclopedia/vehicles/?application_id=e079b7fe335c9af4749be776fbf5fc2b&nation=usa)
and display them as a vertical list?

fyi, I just jumped into coding over the last 40 hours to solve this problem. I understand that the proper solution would be to start with a 6 month crash course in python but I'm really tying to learn by solving this problem. Any suggested code will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you,

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Comment: The close reason is slightly misleading here. We used to have a ”too broad” close reason which included something like ”fails to exhibit basic understanding of the concepts”; but the new(-ish) ”needs more focus” is more specifically about many questions in one. The more correct close reason for this would now be ”needs details or clarity”.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion using a "list comprehension" to extract the names from the list of tanks.

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://api.wotblitz.com/wotb/encyclopedia/vehicles/?application_id=e079b7fe335c9af4749be776fbf5fc2b&nation=usa')
j = response.json()

tanks = j['data'].values()
names = [tank['name'] for tank in tanks]  # list comprehension

print(names)
```

Comment: Wow,  thank you guys so much! I'm glad I was headed down the right path,  but your response were so elegant and efficient. I can't wait to learn more python!

Answer (score 0):

This code would do it. Since you are a beginner I am adding some comments attempting to explain what the code does.
You can also check further on the following concepts:

- REST API
- Python requests module
- Python data structures (dictionary mostly is used here)

Sample code:

```
import requests # library to interact with HTTP

# Get the data
response = requests.get('https://api.wotblitz.com/wotb/encyclopedia/vehicles/?application_id=e079b7fe335c9af4749be776fbf5fc2b&nation=usa')
# Transform the reponse in python dictionary
data_from_api = response.json()

# Get only the part of data for which we care
tanks = data_from_api.get("data")

tank_names = [] # initialize empty list

# Tanks are now a dictionary as well.
# we want to get all the keys and all the values from them
# and from the values (also dictionaries) we want to extract the name value
for tank, specs in tanks.items():
    
    tank_names.append(specs.get("name"))
print(tank_names)
```